# Set telerik radnumeric textbox property for all controls on page

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I have several pages in an ASP.NET web application and each consist of multiple RadNumericTextBoxes. I want to set the following telerik property for all of the RadNumericTextBoxes at once instead of on each individual control:

IncrementSettings InterceptArrowKeys="False"

Is there a way to do this? The ultimate goal is to not have the up and down arrows increment and decrement the values in the controls.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this for example go to search box 
[image] change the scope to whole project and in the search put

```
<telerik:RadNumericTextBox
```

and in the replace box put

```
<telerik:RadNumericTextBox InterceptArrowKeys="False"
```

then replace the whole thing.

Comment: please upvote and accept it as an answer if helpfull

Comment: This would be one way to set that property for each control which is what I want to avoid. I was looking for a way to set the property at a global level. Kind of like a css implementation on a main <div> tag.

Comment: Okey As far my knowledge the style like color font can be set for any control on the whole project but havn't seen such thing

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this usin implicit localization with local resource files. (Details in this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw69ke6f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)). Though meant for localization, local resource files can define any property.

(I was also interested in something like that, but in global level i.e. to define some way my own default properties for controls site-wide.)